# DNN Portal and Page relative images in custom skin css

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I have a custom skin that I designed.  It is used on more than one portal that I manage.  I want to add the ability change a header image based on the page that is being displayed.  This image is a background and I don't want to use a content pane to achieve this.  Also, I would prefer to not use Java script either (but I have a feeling this will be necessary)

I know how to reference the skin path for resources, but this would put the same image on every portal and page.  I want to have a default image like header_bg.jpg in an /images folder in each portal that uses the skin.

So I want to know if there is a way to get the relative root of the portal from the skin css file that is being used by that portal?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the CSS into Portal.css for each of the portals, that gets loaded on every page of a DNN site, depending on which portal it is.

Portal.css loads after container and module CSS files.

Comment: ha, obvious.  I totally forgot about that.